# How do I generate rollback scripts for Entity Framework 6

Tags: continuous-integration, entity-framework-6

If I have a project built with Entity Framework 6, and as part of the CI process I would like to generate rollback migration scripts in case any migrations go wrong. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The rollback scripts can be generated using the `ef6.exe` tool that is provided as part of EntityFramework 6.4.4 nuget package. If you are using an earlier release of EntityFramework 6, e.g. 6.1, note that `ef6.exe` does not support it. However, a workaround is provided as part of the powershell script below.

```
# Usage:
#  Main -Dll bin\Release\My.Project.dll
#
Function Main
{
    [CmdletBinding()] param ($Dll)

    $script:ef64_exe = "~\.nuget\packages\entityframework\6.4.4\tools\net45\any\ef6.exe"

    Write-Host "$ef64_exe exists = $(Test-Path $ef64_exe)"

    $TempDir = "C:\Temp\EFWork"
    
    If (Test-Path $TempDir) { RmDir $TempDir -Recurse }
    
    mkdir $TempDir | Out-Null 

    $OutputDir = Split-Path $Dll

    Copy-Item $OutputDir\* $TempDir -Recurse

    $TempDll = "$TempDir\$(Split-Path $Dll -Leaf)"

    Use-EF644 $TempDll

    Update-Database

    $MigrationNames = Get-MigrationName $TempDll
    
    $MigrationNames | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_ }

    $MigrationNameLast = $MigrationNames | Select-Object -Last 1

    For ($i = $MigrationNames.Length; $i -gt 0; $i--)
    {
       If ($i -eq 1)
       {
         Get-RollbackScript $TempDll -From $MigrationNameLast -To "0"
       }
       Else
       {
         Get-RollbackScript $TempDll -From $MigrationNameLast -To $MigrationNames[$i-1]
       }
    }
}

Function Use-EF644($Dll)
{

  Write-Host "change binding redirect to EF 6.4.4"

  $config = [xml] (Get-Content "$Dll.config")

  $ef = $config.configuration.assemblyBinding.dependentAssembly `
        | Where-Object Name -eq "EntityFramework"
  if ($ef)
  {
     $ef.ParentNode.RemoveChild($ef)
  }

  $node = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
  $node.LoadXml(  @"
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.4.4.0" newVersion="6.4.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
"@)

  $imported = $config.ImportNode($node.FirstChild, $true)
  $config.configuration.runtime.assemblyBinding.AppendChild($imported) | Out-Null
  $config.Save("$Dll.config")

  Write-Host "Replace with EntityFramework.6.4.4"

  $Directory = Split-Path $Dll
  Copy-Item "~\.nuget\packages\entityframework\6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll" $Directory -Force
}

Function Update-Database($Dll)
{
   Write-Host "Update database to latest version so that rollback scripts can be computed."
   & $ef6_exe database update -a "$Dll" --config "$Dll.config"
}

Function Get-MigrationName($Dll)
{
    Write-Host "get migrations for $Dll $ef64_exe"

    Write-Verbose "$ef64_exe database update --prefix-output -a `"$Dll`" --script --config `"$Dll.config`" --source 0"

    $migrations = `
      & $ef64_exe database update --prefix-output -a "$Dll" --script --config "$Dll.config" --source 0 `
        | select-string "INFO:\s+Applying explicit migration: (.+)\."
    $migration_names = $migrations | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value }
    Write-Output $migration_names
}

Function Get-RollbackScript($Dll, $To)
{
    Write-Host "getting rollback script down to $to"
    Write-Verbose "$ef64_exe database update --prefix-output -a `"$Dll`" --script --config `"$Dll.config`"  --target $to"

    $Output = (& $ef64_exe database update --prefix-output -a "$Dll" --script --config "$Dll.config"  --target $to ) 
    $Output | % { Write-Verbose $_ }
    $scripts = $Output `
               | select-string "data: (.+)" `
               | ForEach-Object  { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value }

    Write-Output ($scripts -Join "`n")
}
```